# Django: admin.site.site_header set, but not visible for own pages

Tags: django, django-admin

I set `admin.site.site_header = 'Fooo'` like explained in the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_header

This works very nice for all normal admin-pages.

I have an additional (custom) page which I want to look like the admin page.

I use `{% extends 'admin/base_site.html' %}` in my template.

On this page site_header 'Fooo' is not displayed. The default django string is visible.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't shown your custom page, but it sounds like you didn't add `site_header` to the template context used to render [`admin/base_site.html`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of user Alasdair I found this solution:

Since I have several Views where I need this context variable, I wrote a Mixin:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class PageMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PageMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['site_header'] = admin.site.site_header
        return context
```

Usage of the PageMixin:

```
class WebTestView(PageMixin, FormView):
    ....
```